# Por que o Retrofit lança uma exceção quando o code de status é 204?

Tags: android, http, restful, retrofit, http-status

Após uma consulta *GET* apenas para verificar se um conteúdo existe no servidor, o retorno é 200 (existe) ou 204 (não existe).

Por que o Retrofit dispara a exceção abaixo quando o servidor retorna o **Status Code:** *204 No Content*?

> java.net.ProtocolException: HTTP 204 had non-zero Content-Length: 37

Usando o Postman, por exemplo, não dá erro algum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na classe `okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine`, no método `Response proceed(Request request)` existe o seguinte:

```
  Response var6 = HttpEngine.this.readNetworkResponse();
  int var9 = var6.code();
  if((var9 == 204 || var9 == 205) && var6.body().contentLength() > 0L) {
    throw new ProtocolException("HTTP " + var9 + " had non-zero Content-Length: " + var6.body().contentLength());
  } else {
     return var6;
  }
```

Então se retornar 204 ou 205 **E `contentLength` do `body` for maior que `0`**,

vai estourar um `ProtocolException`

No seu caso, está retornando 204 e seu `contentLength` é 37 !

Pode se interceptar um `ProtocolException` e tratar esta situação:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
  @Override
  public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
      Response response;
      try {
        response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
      } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        response = new Response.Builder()
            .request(chain.request())
            .code(204)
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
            .build();
      }
    return response;
  }
});
```

Mas isto pode acarretar mais problemas, pois não é apenas neste contexto que se lança esta `Exception`.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Dei uma olhada na classe e vi, mas esperei alguém responder. O servidor tava retornando conteúdo quando não era pra retornar.